# “White-listing” USB drives in antivirus?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, anti-virus, blocking, access-control

I was just reading some antivirus manuals and came across a mention that the antivirus will block all read/write access to removable media except for white-listed drives.

Can somebody explain to me the concept of white-listing storage media? What is the process by which a pen-drive can acquire white-list status?

Comment: Are you translating the manual? Do you mean *white-list*?

Comment: Yes. White-List. I will edit the question.

Comment: Which antivirus bud?

Comment: @tumchaaditya: I was going through the e-scan antivirus where I was looking at the USB protection options and I tumbled across this.

Comment: I don’t know. If they had voted it down before I edited to clarify the question, that would be understandable, but they voted down [*after*](http://superuser.com/posts/680675/timeline) the question was clear. Maybe they were just being jerks who thought your question was too easy because they knew the answer themselves and expected *everybody* to know as well. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: See this is bad. Nobody is expected to know everything. The sole purpose of Stack Exchange is to share knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to access-control, there are two ways you can do it:

- Black-listing = “*allow everything, except the ones in the list*” = “*block only the ones in the list*”
- White-listing = “*block everything, except the ones in the list*” = “*allow only the ones in the list*”

Each method has pros and cons:

- Black-list

  - Pro: easier to use because everything is allowed by default
  - Con: less secure because you have to manually block threats, but you cannot know of *all* threats
- White-list

  - Pro: more secure because everything is blocked by default, so even unknown threats are blocked
  - Con: it’s more work to use because you have to manually allow everything that is safe

USB drives are often an easy way to get infected because of [AutoPlay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoPlay). To prevent this, antivirus programs usually use a white-list method in order to be more secure. Instead of saying “*allow all USB drives except the ones in the black-list*”, they say “***block*** all USB drives except the ones in the white-list”. This way even new drives that have never been plugged into the computer before will automatically be blocked.

The process to white-list a drive depends on the specific antivirus program you are using. Usually there will be a configuration screen somewhere in the program called “Exceptions” or something similar, which will allow you to add files, folders, and drives to the white-list. There’s a few examples below. For eScan, there is actually [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SR0gpTh16WM) that demonstrates the process.

---

[image: Avira’s Exceptions dialog]

[image: Microsoft Security Essential’s Exceptions dialog]

[image: AVG’s Exceptions dialog]

Comment: Good answer, as an extra note, sometimes people block all USB drives and then whitelist a select few in an effort to stop people from walking away with company data.